# Convolutional Neural Networks filter

Tags: neural-network, conv-neural-network

When coding a convolutional neural network I am unsure of where to start with the convolutional layer. When different convolutional filters are used to produce different feature maps does that mean that the filters have different sizes (for example, 3x3, 2x2 etc.) ?

Answer (score 0):

In most examples which is a good indication of how to go about coding a convolutional neural network, you will find to start with 1 convolutional layer and pass layer sizes, 3x3 window, input data features.

```
 model.add(Conv2D(layer_size, (3,3), input_shape = x.shape[1:]))
```

The filter sizes usually only differ in the max pooling layer e.g 2x2.

```
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)))
```

Layer sizes are usually selected from range `layer_size = [32, 64,128]` and you can do the same to experiment with different `convolution_layers = [1,2,3]`

Answer (score -1):

I've never seen different kernel sizes for the filters in the same layer, although it is possible to do so, is not a default option the frameworks I have used. What makes filters yield different feature maps are the weights.

Along different layers different kernel sizes are used because the idea of the convolutional networks is to gradually reduce dimensionality through downsampling layers (max pooling for example), so in deep levels you have smaller feature maps and a smaller filter keeps it convolutional and less fully connected (having a kernel the same size as the image is equivalent to have a dense layer).

If you're starting with convolutionals I recommend you to play with [this](http://scs.ryerson.ca/~aharley/vis/conv/) interactive visualization of a CNN, it helped me with a lot of concepts.